# How to properly use FrameLabel with the new PlotLayout feature?

Tags: plotting, labeling, grid-layouts, ticks, frame

Behold! MMA 13 brought us closer to getting publication-ready plots. I wonder if we can solve this one once and for all with a nifty & modern wolfram syntax.

I'd like to have 4 plots with each y-axis (FrameLabel) called differently, but with a common x-axis FrameLabel. Like on the image below which was done using Multicolumn hackery (aka, trial and error):
[image]

Nowadays the positioning and ticks can be handled nicely (much nicer than above) with simple `PlotLayout->{"Column",1}`, but how can label the Frames?

I attach a random, but counterintuitive result that MMA 13 currently gave me to illustrate the problem.

Also is there a way to control the spacing between plots when using `PlotLayout`? It would be very nifty to have them close together so that the frames touch, but the ticks don't overlap.

[image: Problematic FrameLabel]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use yet-to-be-documented options `"ColumnLabels"` and `"RowLabels"` as `Method` sup-options:

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[3, {4, 20}], 
 PlotLayout -> {"Row", 2}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 Method -> {"Spacings" -> {5, 5}, 
   "ColumnLabels" -> 
      {{"bottom left", "top left"}, {"bottom right", "top right"}}, 
   "RowLabels" -> 
      {{ "left top", "right top"}, { "left bottom", "right bottom"}}}]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListLinePlot[RandomReal[3, {9, 20}], PlotLayout -> {"Row", 3}, 
  Method -> {"Spacings" -> {5, 5}, 
    "ColumnLabels" -> 
      ({# <> " - bottom", # <> " - top"} & /@ {"col1", "col2", "col3"}), 
    "RowLabels" -> 
      ({# <> " - left", # <> " - right"} & /@ {"row1", "row2", "row3"})}], 
 ImagePadding -> {{0, 120}, {0, 120}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @kglr that's exactly what I've been looking for! And really "exactly looking for", but I've lacked the skills to search in available "Method" parameters.

Comment: How can one learn all the available options/parameters of the "Method" option?

Comment: @Ranza, unfortunately afaik there is still no systematic/documented way to discover all `Method` sub-options. The way I bumped into the solution posted is sort of a  cargo-cult ritual:  trace/spelunk/squint/wish/try/stepback/"howWouldIHaveDoneIt"/... I used `Trace[ ListLinePlot[RandomReal[3, {2,5}],  PlotLayout -> {"Row", 2}, FrameLabel->{{"A","B"},{"C","D"}}]]` which produced a lot of warning/error messages some of which contained the text ``System`GraphicsAlignDump`axisstyle``. Then I used ``Names["*`*Graphics*Align*"]``  which returned a few results, among them ``Charting`GraphicsAlign``.

Comment: ... I tried ``Information[Charting`GraphicsAlign]`` (or ``Options[Charting`GraphicsAlign]``)to get a list which contained `"ColumnLabels"`, `"RowLabels"` etc. After several trials/errors (having seen before that using options of internal functions called by a *Plot/*Chart functions as `Method` sub-options in the calling function sometimes works) I found `Method -> {"ColumnLabels" -> ...` gives the desired result.

Comment: btw, sometimes powerful incantations like `"blahblah" ->"blah"` delivers the cargo: try for example `FindRoot[{x - 1, 10 (y - x^2)}, {{x, -1}, {y, 1}},  Method -> {"Newton", "blahblah" -> "blah"}]` and `FindRoot[{x - 1, 10 (y - x^2)}, {{x, -1}, {y, 1}}, 
 Method -> {"loremipsum" -> "dolor"}]` :)

Comment: Great, thank you! And how would you go about setting PlotRange for each of the plots? The plots can get nasty when one tries to plot `RandomReal[3, {4, 20}] + {1, 2, 3, 100}` instead of `RandomReal[3, {4, 20}]`

Comment: @Ranza, i don't know how the answer re individual plot ranges otomh. Please consider posting it as a new question.

Comment: Looks like this question [was asked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195713/vertical-ranges-of-column-in-listlineplot-in-12), but the answer does not involve PlotLayout, which is a pitty.

Answer (score 1):

In a format similar to what the OP asked, and inspired by @kglr, I came up with this:

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[3, {4, 20}], PlotLayout -> {"Column", 1}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{10, 20}, {10, 10}}, 
 Method -> {"Spacings" -> {0, 5}, 
   "ColumnLabels" -> {"bottomCommonLabel"}, 
   "RowLabels" -> {{"", "rightTop"}, {"", "righttNext"}, {"", 
      "rightNext2"}, {"", "rightBottom"}}}]
```

The plot sizes aren't what I'd like and there seems to be padding at the top, so I'm missing something that should be done.

Result:
[image: Column of graphs with common x-axis]

Comment: Yes I get the very odd padding too unfortunately.